# Customize UIDatePickerViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uidatepicker

I wish to change the `UIDatePickerView` for my custom requirement which is not available currently with `UIDatePickerView`.

I would like to copy and create the **UIDatePicker.h** and **UIDatePicker.m**

**However, I am not able to locate the UIDatePicker.m**

Can anyone help me locating **UIDatePicker.m**?

Comment: What are you looking to change the UIDatePicker to?  You should subclass the UIDatePickerView instead of overwriting a core library file.

Comment: What is it you actually want to do? Changing the header file won't change how the view behaves, and the implementation file isn't publicly available. What behaviour are you looking to add or change?

Comment: I do not intend to overwrite the library. However, I wish to copy and make a custom implementation of the same.
I wish to display on the Month and Year component and hide the date component.

Comment: You want UIDatePicker.m?  Get a job at Apple.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your inputs.

Yes I finally did subclass UIPickerView and did mange to create something for myself.

Cheers,
Kunjal

Answer (score 0):

Either SubClass `UIDatePicker` or use Categories to add required features.

You can also look for custom UIDatePicker controls at websites like www.cocoacontrols.com